# What is the name of the argument that disallows the current state or condition of things as it is independent of reason?

Tags: logic

I remember a few years ago I came across a description of a framework of argument that disallowed the use of the current (or any other) state in the argument given that the state is independent of how good the reasoning is. I can't find any reference to it any longer, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Logical validity?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity#Validity_and_soundness) The **validity** of a deduction is not affected by the truth ("state" or "condition") of the premises or the truth of the conclusion.

Comment: [Ceteris paribus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceteris_paribus) ?

Comment: what do you mean with "state"?

Comment: umm..supposed in a hare and tortoise race you are trying to determine who is better. suppose further the race lasts forever and some of the time the hare is ahead and sometimes the hare is asleep and the tortoise is ahead. clearly in this case you can't claim the hare (or tortoise) is better simply because it is ahead since 'being ahead' is transient. there is a system of debate that specifically requires exclusion of transcient events and states.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether you are referring to this, but in medieval [disputations *de obligationibus*](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/obligationes/), the rules of the disputation game admitted positing false propositions.

In fact, the idea of the game was to make one of the players "concede" two contradictory propositions: he was obliged to admit any *positio* (proposition posited) as long as it was contingent (albeit false), and he then should be guided by certain principles in counterfactual reasoning in accepting other propositions. This more or less fits the description in your question.

Apart from the SEP entry linked above, a very good resource on obligation games and medieval theories of modality in general is Knuutila's *Modalities in Medieval Philosophy*.